# inner join on column A then on column B if A is empty then column C if B is empty

Tags: sqlite, join

I have a large query which combines a lot of tables. I don't want to make this question to complicate so I will try to ask it easy:

suppose I have 3 columns:

```
table1_device_id, table2_device_id, table3_device_id
```

I know want to achieve this:

Do a left join on table1_device_id, if that column is null, do a left join on table2_device_id,.. (same for table 3..)

I have following example for 1 table now:

```
left join query_505727 as inside_weather_data on y.datetime_weather = inside_weather_data.time AND  (a.monitor_id is null or a.monitor_id = inside_weather_data.device_id)
```

but how to do that for multiple?

my query:

```
select y.datetime_weather, a.site_name as site_name,a.name as house_name, a.name1 as floor_name,a.airspace_name as room_name, a.registration,a.monitor_id, device_color_table.device_id as device_color_device_id, inside_weather_data.device_id as weather_device_id, rdi_data.device_id as rdi_device_id, a.monitor_code as monitor_code, a.alarm_type,a.created_at_date as alarm_date,device_color_table.colors as LED_color_status, rdi_data.value as RDI, ROUND(inside_weather_data.min_inside_temp, 2) as min_inside_temp, ROUND(inside_weather_data.max_inside_temp, 2) as max_inside_temp, y.max_temp as max_outside_temp, y.min_temp as min_outside_temp, y.average_temp as avg_temp, a.alarm_type, a.priority, a.translation_code,a.created_at
from query_505641 as y
left join  query_505127 as a on a.created_at_date = y.datetime_weather
left join query_505241 as device_color_table on device_color_table.datetime = y.datetime_weather AND device_color_table.device_id = a.monitor_id
left join query_506556 as rdi_data on rdi_data.time = y.datetime_weather and rdi_data.device_id = a.monitor_id AND device_color_table.device_id is null
left join query_505727 as inside_weather_data on y.datetime_weather = inside_weather_data.time AND inside_weather_data.device_id = a.monitor_id AND coalesce(device_color_table.device_id, rdi_data.device_id) is null
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the table that you want to join to these 3 tables is `table` then use these LEFT joins:

```
....
from table t
left join table1 t1 on t1.table1_device_id = t.device_id
left join table2 t2 on t2.table2_device_id = t.device_id and t1.table1_device_id is null
left join table3 t3 on t3.table3_device_id = t.device_id and coalesce(t1.table1_device_id, t2.table2_device_id) is null
```

Comment: thanks for the help. It looks better but I still have some records where I have an other t.id than t2 or t3 id. (it looks like it's only when there is nog t1 id). I posted my query in the question

Comment: These are LEFT joins, meaning that the result is **all** the rows of t even if there are no matches in any of the other 3 tables. If you want only the rows of t where there is at least 1 match in the other tables add a WHERE clause: `WHERE coalesce(t1.table1_device_id, t2.table2_device_id, t3.table3_device_id) is not null`

Comment: No I don't want that. Sorry it was maybe unclear. See the screenshot in original question.
columns are datetime, t,t1,t2,t3. When t1 is empty, the id's don't match anymore, still there are matches available as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: If t has no match with t1,t2,t3, I only want to see the data from t3

Comment: In your screenshot there are not any nulls. Why? There should be nulls for the columns coming from the unmatched tables, because for any row of t only 1 of the tables at most should match. It would be better to post sample data and expected results, preferably in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27

Comment: the 3th column are all nulls

Comment: sorry it's very difficult to do it with fiddle as i'm running the query with redash and it's a crossdb query